# Why is my keylistener not working?

Tags: java, layout, user-interface

Why is my keyListener not working in this code? Can somebody explain this to me? I have been trying to add it to my frame but it still does not work when i run the file... Have been trying to do alot of things but still cant figure it out ^.^

```
 package week3.position;

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Container;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Jelle Siderius
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createFrame();
    }

    public static void createFrame() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setTitle("Vierkanten");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Dimension dlp1 = new Dimension(300, 500);
        final JPanel lp1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        lp1.setPreferredSize(dlp1);

        JPanel lp11 = new JPanel();
        lp11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 500));

        JPanel lp12 = new JPanel();
        lp12.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 500));

        JPanel lp2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        lp2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        lp2.setSize(200, 500);

        JPanel lp21 = new JPanel();
        Dimension d21 = new Dimension(200, 100);
        lp21.setPreferredSize(d21);
        lp2.add(lp21, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JPanel lp22 = new JPanel();
        Dimension d22 = new Dimension(200, 300);
        lp22.setPreferredSize(d22);

        JLabel lable22 = new JLabel("Aantal vierkanten: ");
        final JTextField text22 = new JTextField(10);
        JButton button22 = new JButton("Teken!");

        ActionListener buttonClick = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int aantal = Integer.parseInt(text22.getText());
                Circle circle = new Circle(aantal);
                lp1.add(circle);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();

                if (circle.getekend == true) {
                    lp1.removeAll();
                    lp1.updateUI();
                    lp1.add(circle);

                    frame.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        lp22.add(lable22);
        lp22.add(text22);
        lp22.add(button22);

        button22.addActionListener(buttonClick);

        lp2.add(lp22, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JPanel lp23 = new JPanel();
        Dimension d23 = new Dimension(200, 100);
        lp23.setPreferredSize(d21);
        lp2.add(lp23, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(lp1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(lp2, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". Is it never called or does it have an unexpected result? Did you try tracing something to see if actionPerformed is called?

Comment: I get no messages back in my console...

Comment: Read the second note on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: Thank you! That was what i was searching for!